# matching text in brackets

Tags: regex, bash

A fairly simple goal - I thought: matching text in brackets which contains two comma-separated parts, like e.g.:
[first,second]
That's the whole line, I used bash 4.1.

I tried a pattern match like this and tried to use BASH_REMATCH afterwards:

```
[[ "$file_contents" =~ ^[\ []\(.*\),\(.*\)\ []\ ]$ ]] && echo YES || echo NO
```

I tried several little modifications but got either no match at all or wrong contents of BASH_REMATCH.

What's wrong about the regular expression above?

Comment: What Kind of brackets? ( ) or [ ]? I am no Bash expert, but the RegEx itself looks odd.

Comment: do the brackets go recursively? if yes, it's not good for regex.

Comment: It is a complicated way of using literal brackets in regex. It works on several systems but not on my target system. I think it is an old way out of trouble with brackets and no longer needed. But I'm neither bash expert nor regex expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in bash `3.2.25(1)` from CentOS 5 but fails in bash `4.1.2(1)` from CentOS 6:

```
$ file_contents="[word1 word2,word3 word4]"
$ [[ $file_contents =~ ^\\[([^,]+),([^]]+)\\] ]]; echo $?
0
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="[word1 word2,word3 word4]" [1]="word1 word2" [2]="word3 word4")'
```

- Start of string: `^`
- Literal open square bracket: `\\[`
- Capture start: `(`
- One or more of class of anything but comma: `[^,]+`
- Capture end: `)`
- Literal comma: `,`
- Capture start: `(`
- One or more of class of anything but close square bracket: `[^]]+`
- Capture end: `)`
- Literal close square bracket: `\\]`

This works in bash `4.1.2(1)` from CentOS 6 but fails in bash `3.2.25(1)` from CentOS 5:

```
[[ $file_contents =~ ^\[([^,]+),([^]]+)\] ]]; echo $?
```

- Start of string: `^`
- Literal open square bracket: `\[`
- Capture start: `(`
- One or more of class of anything but comma: `[^,]+`
- Capture end: `)`
- Literal comma: `,`
- Capture start: `(`
- One or more of class of anything but close square bracket: `[^]]+`
- Capture end: `)`
- Literal close square bracket: `\]`

Comment: copy und paste auf meinem Zielsystem (CentOS mit bash 4.1.2) liefert als Ergbnis für $? eine 1, nicht 0. BASH_REMATCH ist entsprechend leer.

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot. Can you link me to an explaination for those differences? It is a bit frustrating. Did not think that something that 'basic' differs from (bash) version to version.

Comment: @AlexanderStippler I can't point you to documentation of the difference but I can point you at the changelog item about the change. Point `l` in [this email](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2009-02/msg00018.html) is talking about the change (in terms of backward compatibility). It doesn't seem to be talking about the same thing but it is. (`shopt -s compat31` here causes the bash 4 version to fail and the bash 3 version to work here).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\[\w+,\w+\]
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC7oD2/1)**

[image]

Comment: funktioniert auf meinem Zielsystem (CentOS mit bash 4.1.2) ebenso wenig.